# Is it possible to use RDP to share account?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, android

I'm trying to use an android to control a win11 pc that is close to me but that I can't always easily access physically. I have set up everything for it to work and it does. The problem is that when I log in using android and the windows RDP software for it, it logs me out of the account I run. I need to *share* the desktop. I used to use teamviewer, vnc, etc but I figured I'd try RDP(I usually keep it disabled completely). That is, most of the time I will be using the tablet to do things but sometimes it is easier just to go to the PC to do it(I'm using the tablet as a "control surface" for the pc).

Is there a way to "share" the account so that when I log in using the android it does not kick me out to the login screen on the pc? Or am I going to have to go 3rd party again? [I've done the standard stuff of trying to enable multiple connections already but it doesn't seem to work and some have said it only works for server]

I know for a fact that people use RD to log in to peoples computers to "help them" and both share the desktop(e.g., like team viewer, or VNC) so I'm not sure why it is so difficult for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP is the wrong technology to use for screen-sharing, as remote login
to the computer causes the logout of the current session.
Windows Home or Pro only allow one single active session at any one time.

The Microsoft technology that enables remote help with screen sharing is
[Quick Assist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/quick-assist),
which is found on the
[Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/quick-assist/9P7BP5VNWKX5).
Unfortunately, it's only available on computers running Windows 10
version 1607 or later, so not available on Android.

This means that for using Android to share screen with a Windows PC,
you will need to use a third-party product.

Microsoft will have an
[Android client for Intune](https://www.anoopcnair.com/remote-help-for-android-in-intune-support/)
in 2023, which is perhaps not relevant to your case.

Comment: I've seen many videos online of scammers using RDP to log in to peoples computers WHILE that person is on that computer. Can you explain why they were able to do this or are you claiming it can't be done? E.g., the scam-catchers that let the scammers log in to their comp while they screen capture what they are doing. Maybe it was older versions of windows?

Comment: Maybe it was Quick Assist, rather than RDP.

Comment: @Ramhound They were not using TV or any common software like that because when it showed them logging it it said something Remote Desktop in a windows looking dialog. It was likely Quick Assist.